# Extending a class defined in another precistence untit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a class `User` which is in persistence unit `idmalight`. I have to create a class `CMNUser` which extends User but must be in persistence unit `cmn`.

First of all, is it possible?

If yes here is a snippet of the classes:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table( name = "NETHZ_USER" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
public class User extends PersistentObject
{
  fields
  getters
  setters
}


@Entity
@Table( name = "CMN_USER" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
public class CMNUser extends User
{
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinTable( name = "CMN_MAP_USER_TO_DELEGATE" )
    private Set< User >         delegates;

    getter
    setter
}
```

When I try to deploy the application I get the error:

```
     [exec] [#|2014-08-12T16:41:26.755+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeploye
r prepare method|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-08-12T16:41:26.755+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-08-12T16:41:26.755+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[PersistenceUnit: cmnPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFact
ory
     [exec] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cmnPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
     [exec]     at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
     [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     [exec] Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ch.ethz.id.wai.idmanlight.bo.User.permissions[ch.ethz.id.wai.idmanlight.bo.Permission]
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1057)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1586)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1344)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1730)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
     [exec]     at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
     [exec]     ... 38 more
     [exec] |#]
```

permissions is defined in User class as

```
@ManyToMany
private Set< Permission >   permissions;
```

Is this because of the different PUs and entity CMNUser doesn't know of fields set in the parent class(and therefor it not possible to do such things) or there is another reason?